# TF doesn't work even though it's in the tf_tree

Tags: ros, tf-tree, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need a tf between world and map.

This is my starting situation (world and map are not connected):
[image: image description]

Now I establish a simple static transform:
[image: image description]

The two tf_trees are now connected:
[image: image description]

BUT somehow there is still no connection between /world /base_footprint:
[image: image description]

Rviz is complaining about a missing tf as well.

How can I fix this?
Any hints for further investigation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273111/tf-doesn%27t-work-even-though-it%27s-in-the-tf_tree/) by [Jan](https://answers.ros.org/users/32264/jan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your transforms have timestamps that are offset by on the order of 400 seconds which means that there's no valid time to query across the spanning set that you're looking for.

Unrelated, but best practice is to have a tree, not keep inserting parents above map or world.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jan](https://answers.ros.org/users/32264/jan/) on 2017-10-16**:
Wow, you are right haven't noticed!  I don't want to mess with trasnforms below map. Therefore I somehow need to push the world/map transform in the past. Do you know how to do that?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-10-16**:
You should make sure that all the computers in your system have synchronized clocks. https://answers.ros.org/question/11570/ros-time-across-machines/

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-10-16**:
Since this answers your question please accept it. And if you have more followup questions please ask them separately with specific information on how to reproduce them etc.